# Toilet gunk from clean water hole

Tags: toilet

There is black gunk coming from toilet hole that clean water comes from sometimes its chips & spots that just look like bacteria or growth. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this black gunk come out of any other faucets? Have you been able to strain some out of the toilet bowl and get photos?

Comment: Picture of the inside of the tank on top of the toilet, please.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like deterioration of major rubber stuff, so get a plumber to entirely replace ALL of the toilet's components. Noticeable chunks typically indicate your tank gasket is going quick & not just the tank needing to be cleaned. These particles can collect & clog the toilet's functions if not addressed.

This requires removing the tank & you may as well replace the bolts, their washers, the flapper & the fill valve along with the new tank gasket. Probably $400 in parts & labor for a Handyman or Journeyman Plumber ($20-$30 if you do it) & good for at least a decade, so consider doing all toilets to ensure all water wasting is stopped.

However, getting a new toilet(s), that may work vastly better, might be the same Pro price & of course would fix the gunk problem. So, ask the Pro about this option as a quicker & better alternative. Lowe's cheapest Project Source toilets ($100-$130) were wonderfully welcomed replacements for my place when I did them.